# How to make an observation numbering in bold?

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, bold

I'm writing a paper in LIPIcs template.

```
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{\textbf{Observation}}

\newcommand{\robs}[1]{Observation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\rfig}[1]{Fig.~\ref{#1}} 
\newcommand{\rlem}[1]{Lemma~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\rdef}[1]{Definition~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\rthm}[1]{Theorem~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\rpro}[1]{Proposition~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\rcor}[1]{Corollary~\ref{#1}} 
\newcommand{\rse}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
```

However the observation number is not in bold.
I want to make the observation number bold.

How can I do this?

Comment: some of the answers so far assume that you want the *heading* of the observation report to be bold, but your description sounds more like you want the *cross reference* number bold irrespective of the style of the heading.  please clarify.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `definition` style (available though `amsthm` internally loaded by the class) for your `observation` theorem-like structure:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{lipics}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}

\begin{document}

\begin{observation}
test
\end{observation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A small change in your definition will do the job:

```
 \newcommand{\robs}[1]{Observation~\textbf{\ref{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`lipics`](http://www.dagstuhl.de/en/publications/lipics/instructions-for-authors/) uses [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) to set its theorems. You can redefine the generic theorem number setting macro `\@upn`, which defaults to `\textup`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{lipics}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{\textbf{Observation}}
\makeatletter
\let\@upn\textbf% \textup -> \textbf
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{observation}
This is an observation.
\end{observation}
\end{document}
```

A more intuitive way is to redefine the "theorem head spec" (argument `#9` in `\newtheoremstyle`), use an existing style (like in Gonzalo's answer) or define a new theorem style altogether.